# How to display .mp4 sent from server via response-header on client page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response-headers

I'm writing a simple video conversion app using node, express, and ytdl. I want to send the converted .mp4 file to the user so that it can be displayed on the webpage.

Right now, when the response is sent, the client just downloads the file. Setting `Content-Disposition: inline` doesn't work.

server-side code:

```
app.get("/download", (req, res) => {
  var URL = req.query.URL;
  res.header("Content-Disposition", 'inline; filename="ConvertedVideo.mp4"');
  ytdl(URL, {
    format: "mp4"
  }).pipe(res);
});
```

This causes the browser to just download the file. Currently the only client-side code I have related to this is just:

```
var URL = document.getElementById("URL-input").value;
        window.location.href = `https://unplayer.glitch.me/download?URL=${URL}`;
      }
```

This gets the url of the video to be converted and redirects the browser to `/download?URL=${URL}`.

Comment: Why don't you set it as the `src` for a html5 `<video>` element?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. Could you give an example?

Comment: I mean you want to display it in a webpage, so it has to be embedded in an html element on the page. The `<video>` element is what you want to embed it in. Here's the docs on that element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: I know about `<video>` elements, but I'm wondering how I could specify the converted .mp4 file as the video `src`.

Comment: You can use javascript for that. `var video = document.getElementById('video');
var source = document.createElement('source');

source.setAttribute('src', '<your-converted-video-url-here.mp4');`

Comment: There isn't a converted video url. The converted video is just an .mp4 file created by the server which is sent to the client and downloaded by the browser.

Comment: I don't understand why it can't be used as a source URL. Technically speaking every media whether it's an image or a video that gets rendered by the browser is downloaded to the browser cache and displayed. If it's a media file that isn't embedded into an html element, the browser's default action is to download it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201863/discussion-between-thedevelopernextdoor-and-iskandar-reza-razali).